# Setting up transactional emails from WordPress using AWS SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress, amazon-ses

Ive been reading all days different blog all around the web looking for a solution to my problem. For the first time in my life a used AWS VPS (with ubuntu 2.04.1 LTS) to host my Wordpress blog. My problem is I dont know how to send transactional mails (user suscription confirmation, password reset) through it. I set a AWS SES account and already verified a domain and have been granted production access. I dont know what to do next. How can i verify a sender email address using my Dreamhost domain and how can i start sending welcome emails to new users from a custom domain email address?

I found some wordpress plugins such as WP SES but all i get is an empty blank page when i try to access their settings.

Your help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Wordpress, you can easily use a plugin to send through Amazon SES.

Our [AWS re:Invent presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3xncKCdI_0) shows you how to configure Amazon SES and Wordpress to send using the service. We used the [Configure SMTP plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/configure-smtp/) to connect Wordpress with Amazon SES. This plugin sends all email generated by Wordpress through Amazon SES.

Also, you don't need to verify an email address if you have production access and the domain you are sending from is already verified. Amazon SES will accept email from any email address at the verified domain.